# Replace column value from joined table if column name matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables

TABLE_A:

| ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Main First | Firstly Original |
| 2 | Main Second | Secondly Original |
| 3 | Main Third | Thirdly Original |

RESOURCES:

| LANG_ID | CONTEXT_ID | CONTEXT | KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TABLE_A | NAME | Frst Lang 1 |
| 2 | 1 | TABLE_A | NAME | Frst Lang 2 |
| 2 | 2 | TABLE_A | DESCRIPTION | Scnd Lang 2 |

My expected results:

| ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | LANG_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Frst Lang 1 | Firstly Original | 1 |
| 2 | Frst Lang 2 | Scnd Lang 2 | 2 |
| 3 | Main Third | Thirdly Original | NULL |

What I have tried so far is:

```
SELECT        REF.ID, 
              CASE WHEN RES.KEY = 'NAME' THEN RES.VALUE  ELSE REF.NAME END AS NAME,
              CASE WHEN RES.KEY = 'DESCRIPTION' THEN RES.VALUE  ELSE REF.DESCRIPTION END AS DESCRIPTION,
              RES.LANG_ID
         FROM (
                   SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
              ) REF
    LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT * FROM RESOURCES
                     WHERE CONTEXT = 'TABLE_A' 
              ) RES
            ON REF.ID = RES.CONTEXT_ID
```

But it didn't produce the expected result.
How can I succeed this by SQL?

Comment: No. I just want to replace my original table's cell with the value of Resources table if context and key matches

Comment: AND `LANG_ID` matches - I assume at least because otherwise you have multiple substitutions for the same value.

Comment: I failed to get right results

Comment: If explain how my answer gives incorrect results maybe I can help to correct it? It returns the results requested.

Answer (score 2):

Your question could do with some further clarification specifically that `TABLE_A.ID = RESOURCES.LANG_ID`.

Assuming that is correct you can obtain the results you want using `OUTER APPLY` to see if there is a replacement row available from your `RESOURCE` table.

```
declare @TableA table (ID int, [NAME] varchar(32), [DESCRIPTION] varchar(32));

insert into @TableA (ID, [NAME], [DESCRIPTION])
values
(1, 'Main First', 'Firstly Original'),
(2, 'Main Second', 'Secondly Original'),
(3, 'Main Third', 'Thirdly Original');

declare @Resources table (LANG_ID int, CONTEXT_ID int, CONTEXT varchar(32), [KEY] varchar(32), [VALUE] varchar(32));

insert into @Resources (LANG_ID, CONTEXT_ID, CONTEXT, [KEY], [VALUE])
values
(1, 1, 'TABLE_A', 'NAME', 'Frst Lang 1'),
(2, 1, 'TABLE_A', 'NAME', 'Frst Lang 2'),
(2, 2, 'TABLE_A', 'DESCRIPTION', 'Scnd Lang 2');

select A.ID
    , case when N.LANG_ID is not null then N.[VALUE] else [NAME] end [NAME]
    , case when D.LANG_ID is not null then D.[VALUE] else [DESCRIPTION] end [DESCRIPTION]
    , case when N.LANG_ID is not null or D.LANG_ID is not null then A.ID else null end LANG_ID
from @TableA A
outer apply (
  select LANG_ID, [VALUE]
  from @Resources R
  where R.CONTEXT = 'TABLE_A' and R.[KEY] = 'NAME' and R.LANG_ID = A.ID
) as N (LANG_ID, [VALUE])
outer apply (
  select LANG_ID, [VALUE]
  from @Resources R
  where R.CONTEXT = 'TABLE_A' and R.[KEY] = 'DESCRIPTION' and R.LANG_ID = A.ID
) as D (LANG_ID, [VALUE]);
```

Returns:

| ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | LANG_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Frst Lang 1 | Firstly Original | 1 |
| 2 | Frst Lang 2 | Scnd Lang 2 | 2 |
| 3 | Main Third | Thirdly Original | NULL |

Note: Providing sample data as DDL+DML (as shown here) makes it much easier for people to assist.